# Akima interpolation using R with NA values present: how to deal with boundaries

Tags: r, interpolation, na

I have an irregularly spaced set of points and values at these coordinates that represent the sea-surface temperature throughout the ocean. I'm using `interp` from the `akima` package in R to project these onto a regularly space grid.

My code is working just peachy with the exception of NA values that represent land. I could replace these values with a place holder (e.g., -1) or remove them entirely, but either approach causes problems. The former case creates anomalous gradients that throw off the interpolation in the coastal ocean, while the latter smears out values at the shoreline. Is there a standard way of dealing with boundaries when performing interpolations like this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just go in your interpolation output and manually change the boundary regions to whatever behavior you want (apparently not a gradient)?

Comment: @Vlo Thanks for the response. Changing the _output_ of the interpolation wouldn't help, as the values near the boundary have already been calculated according to my choice of NA value.

Comment: I'm saying that you can change those calculated values to whatever you desire.

Comment: But I don't know what those values should be. Indeed, I'm performing an interpolation to calculate what values on my grid should be, including those at the boundary.